# Does the following define a norm?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to prove if $$||(x,y)|| = (|x|^{1/2}+|y|^{1/2})^2$$
is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I have already shown positive definiteness and homogeneity via the following:

Letting $(x,y) = (0,0)$, we obtain:
 $$||(x,y)|| = ||(0,0)|| = (|0|^{1/2}+|0|^{1/2})^2 = 0^2 = 0$$
Also, for arbitrary $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we have:

\begin{align}||\alpha(x,y)|| &= ||(\alpha x, \alpha y)|| \\&= (|\alpha x|^{1/2} + |\alpha y|^{1/2})^2\\&= (|\alpha|^{1/2} |x|^{1/2} + |\alpha|^{1/2} |y|^{1/2})^2 \\&= \alpha||(x,y)||\end{align}

I am stuck on trying to prove the triangle inequality. This is a homework problem so just give me a hint please. Do not give me the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Possible hint. Draw the "unit circle" in the plane for this possible norm. Note that it's not convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Compute $\bigl\|(1,0)\bigr\|$, $\bigl\|(0,1)\bigr\|$, and $\bigl\|(1,1)\bigr\|$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Ahh I see what to do now. Thank you.

Comment: @SamadAhmed If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the acepted one.